# BIND doesn't seem to be fowarding properly

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to use BIND as a forwarding server to two different DNS. When querying example1.example.local I receive an IP but when I query example2.example.local, It can't resolve it. When I directly query the DNS instead of through the forwarder it works fine. Why is the forwarder only working for some queries?

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        forwarders {
                192.168.**.*;
                172.16.**.*;
                };
        forward only;
        dnssec-validation no;
        recursion yes;
        allow-query { any;};
```

Comment: naming a domain .local could cause problems for avahi. read here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352237/avahi-daemon-and-local-domain-issues. best practice suggest to use a real domain to avoid (future) problems

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous comment regarding the use of .local !  See also [wiki artcle about .local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)

The first thing to check is if you have updated the serial number on the master when adding the entry "example2".

After a modification including a changed serial number, restart the named service (or reload)

Check the log file  (/var/log/messages on Centos/Fedora) when reloading the named service, both on the master and the forwarding host, to find any errors related.

To add verbose logging on the named server, use the command `rndc querylog on`
Turn it off by `rndc querylog off`